# How to model a process in pymc where one variable is a moving average of another variable

Tags: python, time-series, pymc

I"m trying to create a model in PyMC where observed variable Y is a moving average of another observed variable X in a time-series, with unknown window size.

My first thought was to create a function that calculates a simple moving average with `window` as argument and then use `pm.Deterministic` to calculate `Y`, but it is impossible to pass the `observed` variable to `pm.Deterministic`.

I also looked through PyMC examples and documentation, where I found AR process, but I cannot find a way to link the two variables together.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?